# Install a driver with devcon.exe

Tags: windows, drivers, installation, device-manager, hid

I have developed a multi-device HID driver, which consists of two devices: a virtual mouse driver and a proxy for it.

The proxy is required for accepting output reports from clients, because mouses are opened exclusively by the Windows kernel.

This is my report descriptor:

```
HID_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR g_reportDescriptor[] = {
    0x05, 0x01,     // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x02,     // USAGE (Mouse)
    0xA1, 0x01,     // COLLECTION (Application)
    0x85,               REPORT_ID_MOUSE_INPUT,
    0x09, 0x01,         // USAGE_PAGE (Pointer)
    0xA1, 0x00,         // COLLECTION (Physical)
    0x05, 0x09,             // USAGE_PAGE (Buttons)
    0x19, 0x01,             // USAGE_MINIMUM (1)
    0x29, 0x03,             // USAGE_MAXIMUM (3)
    0x15, 0x00,             // LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
    0x25, 0x01,             // LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
    0x95, 0x03,             // REPORT_COUNT (3)
    0x75, 0x01,             // REPORT_SIZE (1)
    0x81, 0x02,             // INPUT (Data, Variable, Absolute)
    0x95, 0x01,             // REPORT_COUNT (1)
    0x75, 0x05,             // REPORT_SIZE (5)
    0x81, 0x01,             // INPUT (Constant)
    0x05, 0x01,             // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x30,             // USAGE (X)
    0x09, 0x31,             // USAGE (Y)
    0x15, 0x81,             // LOGICAL_MINIMUM (-127)
    0x25, 0x7F,             // LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (127)
    0x75, 0x08,             // REPORT_SIZE (8)
    0x95, 0x02,             // REPORT_COUNT (2)
    0x81, 0x06,             // Input (Data, Variable, Relative)
    0xC0,               // END_COLLECTION
    0xC0,           // END_COLLECTION(8)

    0x05, 0x01,     // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x00,     // USAGE (Undefined)
    0xa1, 0x01,     // COLLECTION (Application)
    0x85,               REPORT_ID_MOUSE_OUTPUT,
    0x15, 0x00,         // LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
    0x26, 0xff, 0x00,   // LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (255)
    0x95, 0x0b,         // REPORT_COUNT (11)
    0x75, 0x08,         // REPORT_SIZE (8)
    0x09, 0x00,         // USAGE (Undefined)
    0x91, 0x02,         // OUTPUT (Data, Variable, Absolute)
    0xc0            // END_COLLECTION
};
```

I have got a trouble with installing my driver with `devcon.exe`.

It always fails, no matter what I do. I have been playing with my `*.inf` file for eternity and I don't know what to do next. That's how I run `devcon.exe`:

```
.\devcon.exe install .\hidriver.inf "ROOT\UNKNOWN\0000"
```

Output:

```
Device node created. Install is complete when drivers are installed...
Updating drivers for ROOT\UNKNOWN\0000 from D:\share\opt\KMDFDriver\hidriver.inf.
devcon.exe failed.
```

As a result of the operation, it creates a new device named `Unknown device` without children.

When I install my driver from `Device Manager -> Add Legacy Hardware`, everything is fine and a new SampleClass device with two children (a generic mouse and a HID compliant device) is created, so I don't think it is because my `*.inf` file lacks something.

Here is my `*.inf` file:

```
[Version]
Signature="$WINDOWS NT$"
Class=%ClassName%
ClassGuid={78A1C341-4539-11d3-B88D-00C04FAD5171}
Provider=%ProviderName%
CatalogFile=hidriver.cat
DriverVer=01/07/2018

[ClassInstall32]
Addreg=ClassReg
[ClassReg]
HKR,,,0,%ClassName%
HKR,,Icon,,-24

[SourceDisksNames]
1=%DiskName%,,,
[SourceDisksFiles]
hidriver.sys=1
[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir=12

[Manufacturer]
%ManufacturerName%=Microsoft,NT$ARCH$.6.1
[Microsoft.NT$ARCH$.6.1]
%DeviceName%=DefaultInstall,root\hidriver

[DefaultInstall.NT]
CopyFiles=Files
[Files]
hidriver.sys

[DefaultInstall.NT.HW]
AddReg=HWAddReg
[HWAddReg]
HKR,,"LowerFilters",0x00010008,"hidriver"

[DefaultInstall.NT.Services]
AddService=hidriver,0x00000000,hidriverService
AddService=mshidkmdf,0x00000002,mshidkmdfService
[hidriverService]
DisplayName=%ServiceName%
ServiceType=1
StartType=3
ErrorControl=1
ServiceBinary=%12%\hidriver.sys
[mshidkmdfService]
ServiceType=1
StartType=3
ErrorControl=1
ServiceBinary=%12%\mshidkmdf.sys

[DefaultInstall.NT.Wdf]
KmdfService=hidriver,KmdfLibrary
[KmdfLibrary]
KmdfLibraryVersion=$KMDFVERSION$

[Strings]
DeviceName="VARIABLE_1"
DiskName="VARIABLE_2"
ProviderName="VARIABLE_3"
ManufacturerName="VARIABLE_4"
ServiceName="VARIABLE_5"
ClassName="VARIABLE_6"
```

I have also tried to capture `Device manager`s activity with `Process Monitor`, but it does some magic with `DrvInst.exe` and a dozen of temporary files, so I don't think it's the right way to go.

What should I do, guys?

[Update the next day]

I have also tried `pnputil.exe`:

`pnputil.exe /add-driver D:\share\opt\KMDFDriver\hidriver.inf /install`

```
Microsoft PnP Utility

Adding driver package:  hidriver.inf
Driver package added successfully.
Published Name:         oem40.inf
Driver package installed on matching devices.

Total driver packages:  1
Added driver packages:  1
```

Despite of the sweet output, it has no effect.

[Update after the first answer]

`devcon.exe install hidriver.inf root\hidriver` works on win10 and win8.1, but has a small issue on win7. On win7 children device classes are not detected automatically, so I end up with two child unknown devices.

While my HID proxy is able to accept reports being an unknown device, the mouse doesn't work. To fix this I have to manually set the driver for the mouse child via

```
Update driver
-> Browse for driver software on this computer
-> Let me pick from a list of device drivers on this computer
-> Mice and pointing devices
-> Microsoft
-> HID-compliant mouse
```

Is there a robust way of adding such instructions to the INF file to make it automatic?

[Update after some time]
I captured `Device manager`'s activity by `procmon` and I have got a `DrvInst.exe`:

```
DrvInst.exe "2" "211" "HID\VARIABLE_6&COL01\1&1302B6B5&12&0000" "C:\Windows\INF\msmouse.inf" "msmouse.inf:MSMfg.NTamd64:HID_Mouse_Inst:6.1.7600.16385::hid_device_system_mouse" "6fe2f36b3" "0000000000000060" "00000000000005F8" "00000000000005F0"
```

I'll report the experiment's results after a while.

[Device screenshot]

[image: No HWID here, only the device instance path]

[Update with setupapi.dev.log]

I removed the driver completely, then removed the log, then installed the driver and copied all log contents.

[setupapi.dev.log](https://pastebin.com/4NKgDnBQ)

Comment: You'd have better support from [OSR Online](http://www.osronline.com/page.cfm?name=ListServer)(NTDEV List)

Comment: Could you post the messages for your installation from `%windir%\inf\setupapi.dev.log`?

Comment: Yeap, posted on pastebin. Link is above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*.inf` has no target for `ROOT\UNKNOWN\0000`, use `devcon install hidriver.inf root\hidriver`

---

On VirtualBox 5.2.8 + Win7 Pro SP1 x64, I installed [EcoTUIODriver](https://github.com/ecologylab/EcoTUIODriver) (based on [vmulti](https://github.com/djpnewton/vmulti)), and setup succeeded w/o any unknown device. I further built [vmulti](https://github.com/djpnewton/vmulti) with [WDK 7.1.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/other-wdk-downloads) (w/o Visual Studio), and setup succeeded too. I suggest checking your build and test environments.

*View Devices by connection:*
[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not a developer. I answered based on experience with inf-modded driver installer. Check this HID driver on [github](https://github.com/djpnewton/vmulti) for starter (the inf appears to be vmulti/sys/vmulti.inx).

Comment: OP had [trouble](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/179420f2-96fe-43d3-9f62-7c4b14215335/windows-virtual-mouse-driver?forum=wdk) building drivers with WDK10 for Win7. HID-enumerated child devices have no HwID and installation failed thereof.

Answer (score 1):

Various parts of your inf file seem somewhat doubtful, but I don't know
enough to suggest a fix.
But there might be another way of generating a viable inf file
from your project.

I would suggest to use Visual Studio 2017,
[trial version](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/)
if required, then create the inf file from your solution as described
in the Microsoft article
[Creating a Driver Package](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/).
The
[Windows Driver Kit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk)
(WDK) needs to be installed after Visual Studio is installed.

If you have two such packages that you need to install as one,
you might combine them as described in
[Using an Extension INF File](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/using-an-extension-inf-file).

Comment: I use exactly MVS2017 Community and WDK 10. I guess the INF file generation is not available in Community edition. Anyway, thanks for your hint, I'll look into it. I know the problem is with the INF, but I don't know how to fix it either.